# Installation failed when trying to upgrade to a major version of Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

I've an old Symfony project and here is `composer.json`:

```
{
"name": "symfony/framework-standard-edition",
"license": "MIT",
"type": "project",
"description": "The \"Symfony Standard Edition\" distribution",
"autoload": {
    "psr-0": {"": "src/"}
},
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.5.9",
    "symfony/symfony": "*",
    "symfony/console": ">=2.2.3",
    "doctrine/orm": "~2.2,>=2.2.3",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.2",
    "twig/extensions": "~1.0",
    "symfony/assetic-bundle": "~2.3",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "~2.3",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "~2.4",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle": "~2.3",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "~3.0",
    "sensio/generator-bundle": "~2.3",
    "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
    "facebook/php-sdk-v4" : "4.0.*",
    "symfony/finder": "^3.1",
    "sonata-project/core-bundle": "^3.1",
    "sonata-project/seo-bundle": "^2.0",
    "sonata-project/admin-bundle": "^3.6"
},
"scripts": {
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
    ]
},
"config": {
    "bin-dir": "bin"
},
"extra": {
    "symfony-app-dir": "app",
    "symfony-web-dir": "web",
    "incenteev-parameters": {
        "file": "app/config/parameters.yml"
    },
    "branch-alias": {
        "dev-master": "2.4-dev"
    }
} }
```

First I'd use:

```
php composer.phar self-update
```

Then I used below command to upgrade:

```
php composer.phar update
```

And here is the result:

```
 Search for a package: symfony

Found 15 packages matching symfony

   [0] symfony/symfony    [1] rgies/symfony    [2] php-tmdb/symfony    [3] webforge/symfony    [4] lexpress/symfony1    [5] symfony/symfony1  [6] sabaki-dev/symfony1    [7] behat/symfony2-extension    [8] escapestudios/symfony2-coding-standard    [9] smarkio/symfony1   [10] languara/symfony3   [11] m6web/symfony2-coding-standard   [12] irongit/symfony2-stream-response   [13] polishsymfonycommunity/symfony2-mocker-extension   [14] symfony/console

Enter package # to add, or the complete package name if it is not listed: 0
Enter the version constraint to require (or leave blank to use the latest version):
Using version ^3.1 for symfony/symfony
Search for a package: ./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.1.6
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.1.5
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.1.4
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.1.3
    - Installation request for sensio/generator-bundle (locked at v2.5.3, required as ~2.3) -> satisfiable by sensio/generator-bundle[v2.5.3].
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.1.2
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.1.1
    - don't install symfony/finder v3.1.6|don't install symfony/symfony v3.1.0
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.1.0|remove symfony/finder v3.1.6
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.1.0|don't install symfony/finder v3.1.6
    - Installation request for symfony/symfony ^3.1 -> satisfiable by symfony/symfony[v3.1.0, v3.1.1, v3.1.2, v3.1.3, v3.1.4, v3.1.5, v3.1.6].
    - Installation request for symfony/finder (locked at v3.1.6, required as ^3.1) -> satisfiable by symfony/finder[v3.1.6], symfony/symfony[v3.1.6].


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

Comment: Start a new Symfony project to get a working composer.json then use composer require to add additional packages such as the facebook sdk.  Replace your legacy composer.json with the new one, reinstall and then start working your way though the numerous issues you will face.  Unless you have a deep understanding of Symfony then you will be better off upgrading in steps: 2.2 => 2.3 => 2.7 => 2.8 => 3.1 clearing any deprecation notices as you progress.  Or copy your legacy app to the new app bit by bit.

Comment: Thanks but these are hard for me cause I'm newbie but I wanna learn more, Is there any way to fix all errors that I'm face with them?

Comment: I suppose you could hire someone.  Otherwise, you are basically stuck with having to learn how to develop with the Symfony framework.

Comment: Nope as I said I just want to upgrade these project.

Comment: I'd like to second what @Cerad said. There are number of changes between 2.2 and 3.x and you won't find a silver bullet for doing it.

Answer (score 1):

I did it with `php composer.phar self-update` and then `php composer.phar update` successfully changed to symfony 2.8

Comment: Glad you made it! Be sure to check you app for deprecation warnings and errors.  Some of the services are not there anymore and some concepts differ vastly in `2.8` compared to `2.2`